# Quelle est la différence entre « se bloquer » et « se figer », en parlant d’une application mobile qui ne fonctionne pas normalement?

Tags: choix-de-mot, définition

Quand une application est lancée, qu’elle fonctionne correctement et que tout à coup elle ne répond plus, il doit être d’usage de dire que l’application s’est figée ou qu’elle est gelée. Mais qu’en est-il d’une application qui se bloque? Dit-on qu’une application s’est bloquée lorsqu’on arrive pas à la lancer, c’est-à-dire qu’elle se referme aussitôt qu’on clique sur l’icône de ladite application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Figée" implique que toute l'interface est inutilisable, qu'aucun élément graphique ne répond aux interactions de l'utilisateur. Elle devient parfois grisée. Une application qui s'est "bloquée" pourrait avoir certains boutons ou contrôles qui fonctionnent toujours en surface parce qu'il y a un retour visuel aux clics, mais ne font rien.

Je ne pense pas qu'un des deux puisse décrire une application qui s'est refermée (on utilise alors "plantée" ou l'anglicisme "crashée").

Answer (score 3):

Les deux termes correspondent aux termes anglais:

- *se bloquer* = to be blocked
- *se figer* = to be frozen

*Se bloquer* est plus formel, alors que *se figer* est figuratif. En outre, comme il a déjà   été dit dans les autres réponses, *se figer*, normalement, signifie que l'appareil ne marche plus du tout, malgré qu'il  soit allumé. *Se bloquer* signifie seulement qu'on ne peut pas l'utiliser, alors que, possiblement, il fonctionne bien. Par exemple, l'appareil peut être bloqué parce qu'on a saisi trop souvent un mauvais mot-de-passe, parce qu'on n'a pas le droit de l'utiliser dans une certaine zone géographique, etc.

Comment: Appareil ≠ application

Answer (score 2):

***Se figer*** ou ***se bloquer*** sont pour moi sensiblement équivalents. Le premier implique peut-être plus un aspect visuel, c'est l'affichage qui se fige, qui cesse brutalement d'évoluer en conservant un état inachevé (*la video de l'appli de visioconférence s'est figée*) alors que le deuxième peut plus facilement s'appliquer à un service sans affichage (*le serveur de fichiers se bloque*).

D'une application qui n'arrive pas à se lancer, je dirais simplement qu'elle ***ne démarre pas*** ou plus couramment qu'elle ***ne s'ouvre pas***.

Answer (score -1):

Définitions selon le dictionnaire :

figer
verbe transitif
1.
Coaguler (le sang).
2.
Solidifier (un liquide gras) par le froid.

bloquer
verbe transitif

```
1. Figer :
Réunir, mettre en bloc.
Bloquer deux paragraphes
enter preformatted text here
Synonymes :
grouper

2. Bloquer :
Empêcher de se mouvoir.
Un navire bloqué par les glaces.
Synonymes :
immobiliser
```